# Can you determine Protoss Buildings while still under construction?

Tags: starcraft-2

If an opponent protoss warps a building, all buildings look the same, or is there a hint, what kind of building it will be once it is finished?

[image: robotics facility warping in]

Comment: They only Protoss warp-in you can see, is the warps from the Stargate. You cannot see what a build is going to - you can only do so by clicking it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can click on it if you *Enable Enemy Unit Selection* in the Options and the name will be visible. In addition, the outline of the building is faintly visible later on in the warp, and you can make an educated guess based on the time what it is.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to have this enabled? Because you select the wrong units in melee?

Comment: Can you make out the Robo in [this picture](http://www.arbse.net/Files/StarCraft2/id387/robotics_facility_04.jpg) already? (assume you wouldn't see it in the bottom)

Comment: @rubo77 No not at all you want this turned on. It also allows you to click on enemy units and see their upgrades. Very very very important to have this turned on.

Also from what I remember if you make a box to select your units you will only get your units.

Comment: personally I can't see the robo there, but I have never tried to learn to distinguish them. What halfwarr said is right, its very important to have enemy select on and you normally select your own units via boxing anyway.

Comment: You can only see building's outline in the last few seconds of warping in. "Energy ball", like the one pictured, is the same. Don't worry about accidantally selecting enemy units - your ones always take precedence when box selecting, just like your units take precedence above your buildings.

Comment: @OrcJMR Even though the "energy ball" is the same, the shadow/health bar is not. See answers below.

Answer (score 3):

They are all different, either differing in size or shadow.  [Someone posted a good guide to this on /r/starcraft years ago:](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/sc2-strategy/388798-visual-cues-and-buildings-under-construction)

[image]
[Stargate (has shadow), Twilight Council/Gateway, Robotics Facility/Forge.](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/sc2-strategy/388798-visual-cues-and-buildings-under-construction)
I would recommend you just play a game against a Protoss friend, get him to make a lot of money and build every building in a line, scout them before they finish, take a screenshot and compare.

Obviously this only when you don't get time to click on the building when you scout, if you only get a glimpse and you need to know if it's a gate or a robo, or a pylon or a dark shrine (that distinction is more obvious).

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can get a good read for the buildings in production by looking at the width and height of their life bars (under "Gameplay" you have first to activate the life bars – at least for "Damaged"). For example: The life bar of a pylon is seen slightly on top of the warp-circle, the life bar of a cannon is positioned a little bit lower (just inside the circle) and the bar of a dark shrine is positioned way up. Same for the robotics Facility (low), gateway (middle) and starport (up).
You can use this also for Zerg buildings.